# How to add multivalued literals in solrj

Tags: solr, solrj

How do I add multivalued fields when I'm using the Extracting Request Handler?

The documentation says

`literal.<fieldname>`  Populates a field with the name supplied with the specified value for each document. The data can be multivalued if the field is multivalued.|

Using code looking roughly like this

```
HttpSolrClient solr = new HttpSolrClient.Builder("http://localhost:8983/solr/myindex").build();

solr.setParser(new XMLResponseParser());
ContentStreamUpdateRequest req = new ContentStreamUpdateRequest("/update/extract");

ContentStream contentStream = new ContentStreamBase.ByteArrayStream(bytes, xxx);

req.addContentStream(contentStream); 
req.setParam("literal.id", id);
...
req.setParam("literal.keywords", "[foo,bar]");  // Not working

req.setAction(req.getAction().COMMIT, true, true);
```

I have tried several ways of adding multiple values, but it comes out as a literal literal. What I've tried:

```
req.setParam("literal.keywords", "foo,bar");
---
req.setParam("literal.keywords", "[foo,bar]");
---
req.setParam("literal.keywords", "[\"foo\",\"bar\"]");
---
req.setParam("literal.keywords", "foo");
req.setParam("literal.keywords", "bar");
```

None of these results in a list in the index. Any ideas?

Answer (score 1):

I found a solution:

```
ModifiableSolrParams params = new ModifiableSolrParams();
params.set("literal.keywords", "foo", "bar");
params.set("literal.id", resourceUrl);
...
req.setParams(params);
```

The `ModifiableSolrParams` can handle varargs, which setParam can't.